# Rails Sessions Controller Syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, authentication

I am trying to set up the login/session using ruby on rails but I am getting this error when I try to render my login page:

/Users/farhadam/mboddy/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tLBRACK, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' params [:session][:password] ^ /Users/farhadam/mboddy/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end

here is my sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
user = User.validate_login (

    params [:session][:email],
    params [:session][:password]
    )

if User
    sessions[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to login_path
else
    flash[:status] = FALSE
    flash[:alert] = 'Invalid username and password!'

    redirect_to login_path
end
end

def destroy

session[:user_id] = nil
redirect_to login_path
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the arguments for `User.validate_login` in a single line:

```
user = User.validate_login(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
```

Also, on the following line (`if User`), you're presumably testing whether the user object was successfully authenticated. If so, you need to change it to the following:

```
if user
```

Evaluating `User` – the class – is not the same as evaluating the `user` class *instance*. `User` will always evaluate to true (because `User` is never `nil`), so you want to evaluate whether `User.validate_login` successfully assigned a user to the `user` local variable.

Comment: Putting it in a single line did not work either :( I still get the same error. Not sure why this is happening but I am following all the instructions from this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0k6DFIStFY but cant pass this error!

Comment: oh, and you are totally right about the if User vs. if user... just changed it. thank you :)

Comment: Did you remove the space between `params` and the bracketed symbols? I've updated my answer to reflect. Try `params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password]`, with that spacing _precisely_.